# Removing arbitrary spaces throughout SSRS datafield

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that returns drug names with a different number of spaces throughout the datafield.  For example ( '_' = 'space'):

ACZONE_______GEL 5%______(00023367060)

Is there a way to make it look like the following using a VB expression in Visual Studio:

ACZONE GEL 5% (00023367060)

I do not currently have access to address in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex in SSRS.

Use the below expression to replace `_` character by a single white space:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
Fields!YourField.Value,
  "_+",
  " ")
```

Or use this one to replace several white spaces by a single white space:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
Fields!YourField.Value,
  "\s+",
  " ")
```